# remove special character using sed

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

I have a text file that contains following

```
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git/
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc
```

When I run the following command,

```
reponame=$(echo $url | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/.git\/$//' | sed -e 's/.git//')
echo $reponame
```

I am supposed to get

```
abc
```

It fails for the lines ending in `.git/` but it works for the other 2 cases.

Comment: You want `abc` from all three lines?

Comment: Yes, I need it from all the 3 kind of lines.

Comment: Will the part to be extracted always located in the 5th `/`-separated field? I.e., will the string to parse always be something like `1://2/3/4/xxx.git` or could it also be something like `1://2/3/4/5/xxx.git` or `1://2/3/xxx.git`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '.*/\K[^.]+' file.txt
```

The desired portion is extracted by `[^.]+`, `.*/` matches the portion before `abc` and `\K` discards the match.

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git/
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc

$ grep -Po '.*/\K[^.]+' file.txt
abc
abc
abc
```

---

Similar logic using `sed`, using pattern grouping:

```
$ sed -r 's#.*/([^.]+).*#\1#' file.txt 
abc
abc
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question asks for a `sed` solution, however assuming the string to extract is always going to be in the 6th field like in the example this is more easily done using `AWK`:

```bsh
awk -F/ 'match($6, /^[^.]+/, x) {print x[0]}' file
```

- `-F/`: sets the input field separator to `/`;
- `match($6, /^[^.]+/, x)`: if the sixth field matches `^[^.]+` one or more times, stores the matches into an array `x` an executes the following block;
- `{print x[0]}`: prints the first element of `x`.

```
% cat file
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git/
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc
% awk -F/ 'match($6, /^[^.]+/, x) {print x[0]}' file
abc
abc
abc
```